# getDate returning the next day on current time

Tags: javascript

Is this due to the time zones settings on my laptop or is it something more complex?

Current time

```
var dateObj = new Date();

var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
var week = 7;
console.log ('date ',dateObj,' day is ',day);
```

output

```
> date  Mon Jan 14 2019 23:05:35 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)  day is  15
```

edit: that the time that new Date() created (*Mon Jan 14 2019 23:05:35 GMT-0500*) is in fact the correct time I am after.

after considering the information I read in comments, it seems I need to subtract the hourly change ( - 5 ) to get the EST, which seems to be what I'm after.

Comment: Because `var day` is UTC, and `dateObj` is in EST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems I need to subtract the hourly change ( - 5 ) to get the EST

Subtracting `5` is not a good idea, as it doesn't account for daylight savings.

I'd suggest using [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to be safe.

```js
var dateObj = new Date();

//Output as UTC
var utc = { timeZone: "UTC" };
console.log(dateObj.toLocaleString("en-US", utc));

//Output as EST
var est = { timeZone: "America/New_York" };
console.log(dateObj.toLocaleString("en-US", est));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep timezones consistent. Change this:

```
console.log ('date ',dateObj,' day is ',day);
```

To this:

```
console.log ('date ',dateObj.getUTCDate(),' day is ',day);
```

And it will work:

```js
var dateObj = new Date();

var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
var week = 7;
console.log('date ', dateObj.getUTCDate(), ' day is ', day);
```

Comment: I guess the reason I did this is because my time in fact is correct, it is currently the correct local time that new Date() is creating. 

Looking online I see I have to subtract time zone, correct?